# Lazy assignment of python variables

Tags: python

I have the following if statement and I feel it could be made simpler to read by breaking the terms up into their own named variables.

```
if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dirname, 'file.json')) \
or (os.path.isdir(os.path.join(dirname, 'folder'))
and os.listdir(os.path.join(dirname, 'folder')) != []):
```

So it would look something like this:

```
file_exists = os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dirname, 'file.json'))
directory_exists = os.path.isdir(os.path.join(dirname, 'folder'))
directory_not_empty = os.listdir(os.path.join(dirname, 'folder')) != [])
if file_exists or (directory_exists and directory_not_empty):
```

The problem with this is that in the first implementation the and can short circuit and if it does the `directory_not_empty` term is not evaluated, which could cause an error.
When they are broken into variables they are eagerly executed at assignment.
My solution to this was to use a lambda to cause the `directory_not_empty` term to simulate lazy assignment.

```
file_exists = os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dirname, 'file.json'))
directory_exists = os.path.isdir(os.path.join(dirname, 'folder'))
directory_not_empty = lambda:os.listdir(os.path.join(dirname, 'folder')) != [])
if file_exists or (directory_exists and directory_not_empty()):
```

I think this looks quite elegant however the pep8 standard doesn't like assignment of lambdas and using a one line function definition feels very clunky here. The call on `directory_not_empty` and not the others also feels clunky. Is there an elegant way of doing this?

Comment: Is comparing a list to an integer what looks clunky to me.

Comment: Ow! My eyes! Use [import os.path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724348/should-i-use-import-os-path-or-import-os) already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it this way, I would make the `directory_not_empty` variable handle both the check for the presence of the directory and check if its non-empty. Also, if the long lengths are annoying then I would put the directory in its own variable.

```
my_dir = os.path.join(dirname, 'folder')
directory_not_empty = os.path.isdir(my_dir) and (os.listdir(my_dir) != [])
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), if feasible, may also help readability, by itself or in combination with [the accepted answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/390511/357814):

```
# setup
from pathlib import Path
dirname = Path(dirname)
```

```
# Dropped into original code
if (dirname / "file.json").is_file() \
or ((dirname / "folder").is_dir()
and (dirname / "folder").iterdir() != []):
```

```
# Dropped into the accepted answer
my_dir = dirname / "folder"
directory_not_empty = my_dir.is_dir() and (my_dir.iterdir() != [])
```